# What is the best practice for using id as primary key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For a small project i used id as auto-increment primary key.

But my teacher said it is wrong to use auto-increment in id because it skips number when a row is deleted. So what is the best practice for it? i can use uuid but doesn't it affect performance? Also if i make a custom uniq key, will that be really unique?

Comment: I suggest you get another teacher, this one is broken

Comment: @RiggsFolly haha you made my day

Comment: Lol , but apart from jokes, can i know the best practice at least to tell my teacher ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i wish i could do that.

Comment: @cid I thank you.... I am here all week

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with non sequential AutoIncrement `id` fields. It makes not one single iota of difference to anything.

Comment: Yes, that's what's i said too but noting works :(

Comment: All they should be used for is linking subordinate row of other types. Invoice lines to Invoice (for example) Assuming you code correctly or use the builtin cascaded deletes for example and dont leave child records stranded,

Comment: _Yes, that's what's i said too but noting works_ Well you will have to throw it back at Teacher. Get Him/Her to explain why it is such a terrible thing to do. Then pop back here and tell all of us as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay got it,

Comment: It's really unfortunate that the autogeneration nature of keys was named using the "AUTOINCREMENT" clause. Primary keys (and keys in general) need to be **unique**: that's all. No one cares if they are sequential, triangular, plastic, or golden. As long as they are unique, all is good.

Comment: @theimpaler true, but sequentiality does impart additional information (as well as providing a straightforward mechanism for identifying the next row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees uniqueness, *nothing else*.

If you want *consecutive* values (no gaps), then you have to write a lot of code to close up gaps, etc.  But why would you need that?

Often there is a "natural" key that works for the `PRIMARY KEY`.  An example is a table of countries.  The `PRIMARY KEY` can be `country_code CHAR(2)`.

Auto_inc has many cases where a number is skipped, lost, burned, etc.  Another example is `INSERT IGNORE` when it fails for any reason -- the id was already reserved, then not used.

UUIDs/UUIDs are guaranteed unique, but they are not consecutive, so why use it?  Anyway, a uuid is much bulkier.  And, for huge tables, inefficient because of how 'random' they are.  The one argument for uuids is that they can be independently generated by different clients without the help of the database.

Comment: I had a use case for UUIDs, my managers wanted to obfuscate the number of demands to our customers, so they can't evaluate the number of demands we can provide a year, so, instead of having routes such as `/demands/42`, I had to provide something like `/demands/a970fce1-a283-11eb-90a5-02ec58031255`

Comment: Just a nore: I would advise against natural keys and use synthetic keys all the time. It's not a safe choice, since they can change or become duplicate by forces outside the control of the application.

Comment: @Cid - Good example.  Then, for efficiency, the code might start by turning the uuid back into "42" for the rest of the processing.

Comment: @TheImpaler - I understand that counter-argument.  Sometimes the hassle is not reduced.  Consider the split-up of Yugoslavia into multiple countries.

Answer (score 1):

An auto-increment ID can sometimes cause problems, e.g. in situations where you are using replication. In these cases opt for a GUID.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to implement guid in a simple insert qurey?

Comment: @jerry instead of having something like `id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can use `id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT UUID()`

Comment: @Cid okay , i will definitely try that

Comment: But then you need some other unique key to locate the row so you can get the UUID?